# Trying to transpose an array, but getting array out of bounds

Tags: java, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to convert a 2D array. The content of a horizontal row is transferred to vertical column.

```
public static void change(short image[])
{

   int arrayLength = 29; // row length
   int arrayWidth = 10; // column length
   // array with values
   short[][] decompressedImage = new short[arrayLength][arrayWidth]; 

   // array to store transposed image
   short[][] transposedImage = new short[arrayWidth][arrayLength];

   // store transposed values

   for (int i=0;i<arrayWidth; i++){
      for (int j=0;j<arrayLength; j++){
         transposedImage[j][i]=decompressedImage[i][j];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to rotate the array ?

Comment: yes rotate it! -90 degree

Comment: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/Transpose.java.html

Comment: Are arrayLength & arrayWidth dimensions of decompressedImage or transposedImage ??

Comment: @ ray, i can find these online stuffs , but i am trying to workout on what's wrong in my snipped of code.

Comment: @user3504305 I posted a sample example on how the rotation is done for both direction

Comment: can anyone else help ?? not getting the correct piece of code yet!

Comment: transposedImage[j][i]=decompressedImage[i][j]; is not correct. It should be transposedImage[i][j]=decompressedImage[j][i];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how the rotation works, the rotation is really only the middle for loop,(below the comment), I also made it for both directions with output:

```
    String[][] matrix = {{"A","B","C"},{"D","E","F"},{"G","H","I"}};
String[][] tmp = new String[matrix.length][matrix.length];

    //PRINT BEFORE ROTATION
for(int row=0; row<matrix.length;row++){
    for(int col=0; col<matrix.length;col++){
        System.out.print(matrix[row][col] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

    //HERE IS THE ROTATION
for(int row=0; row<matrix.length;row++){
    for(int col=matrix.length-1; col>=0;col--){
        tmp[col][row] = matrix[row][matrix.length-1-col];
    }
}

    //PRINT AFTER ROTATION
System.out.println("Rotated");
for(int row=0; row<matrix.length;row++){
    for(int col=0; col<matrix.length;col++){
        System.out.print(tmp[row][col] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
A  B  C  
D  E  F  
G  H  I  

Rotated

C  F  I  
B  E  H   
A  D  G
```

And if you want to rotate it the second way.

replace the for loop of : `//HERE IS THE ROTATION`

by this:

```
    for(int row=matrix.length-1; row >= 0; row--){
    for(int col=0; col<matrix.length;col++){
        tmp[col][row] = matrix[matrix.length-1-row][col];
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
A  B  C  
D  E  F  
G  H  I  

Rotated

G  D  A  
H  E  B  
I  F  C
```

Answer (score 0):

if lowLength is 29, you only can access to 28.
because index of for starts from 0.

change

```
i < arrayWidth --> i < arrayWidth - 1
i < arrayLength --> i < arrayLength - 1
```

It is just a possibility.

Comment: Are you sure about what you have said?? I believe i<arrayWidth is actually correct to handle that.

Comment: @user3504305 you are right. my mistake.Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

Change below line :

```
 short[][] transposedImage = new short[arrayLength][arrayWidth];
```

instead of

```
short[][] transposedImage = new short[arrayWidth][arrayLength];
```

This is your code after change :

```
int arrayLength = 29; // row length
int arrayWidth = 10; // column length
short[][] transposedImage = new short[arrayLength][arrayWidth];
short[][] decompressedImage = new short[arrayWidth][arrayLength];

// store transposed values
for (int i=0;i<arrayWidth; i++){
  for (int j=0;j<arrayLength; j++){
     transposedImage[j][i]=decompressedImage[i][j];
  }
}
```

Comment: @ yagnesh, i think i was unclear in the begining. check my codes again.

Comment: @user3504305 than you need to change `transposedImage[i][j]=decompressedImage[j][i];` this line

Answer (score 0):

Assuming  `arrayLength & arrayWidth` to be the `length & width` of `decompressedImage`, the loop construct

```
for (int i=0;i<arrayWidth; i++){
  for (int j=0;j<arrayLength; j++){
     transposedImage[j][i]=decompressedImage[i][j];
  }
}
```

is actually in accordance with the dimensions of `transposedImage` and NOT of `decompressedImage`i.e. your loop variables `i & j` take the dimensions of transposedImage.

Thus change the statement

```
 transposedImage[j][i]=decompressedImage[i][j];
```

to

```
transposedImage[i][j]=decompressedImage[j][i];
```

I guess that should help.

Answer (score 0):

you defined the arre `transposedImage` of dimension `[arrayWidth][arrayLength]` but, while you are accessing the array, you are looping until `[arrayLength][arrayWidth]`, notice the `i` and `j` loop of yours. according the loop, it should be,

```
transposedImage[i][j]=decompressedImage[j][i];
```

and NOT

```
transposedImage[j][i]=decompressedImage[i][j];
```

corrected code segment,

```
short[][] decompressedImage = new short[arrayLength][arrayWidth];
short[][] transposedImage = new short[arrayWidth][arrayLength];
for (int i=0;i<arrayWidth; i++){
  for (int j=0;j<arrayLength; j++){
     transposedImage[i][j]=decompressedImage[j][i];
  }
}
```